# Confusion regarding TFS and creating packages with custom versioning

Tags: tfs, msbuild, nuget, nuget-package

I'm trying to set up a TFS build that will create/pack a package, however, I am unclear on the versioning. We currently manually create packages with the versioning YEAR.MONTH.DAY.INCREMENT and I am trying to replicate that automatically in the build.

I can't seem to upload a picture at the moment but I'm not sure what to put in the Major, Minor, and Patch fields in order to set the date of the build. I also want to put some sort of "alpha" suffix along with a timestamp on the end (i.e., the INCREMENT).

How can I achieve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to `use the data and time` (which you can specify the Major, Minor, and Patch value with it) to automatic package versioning.

Then you can try to use the environment variable to version it with suffix in a CI build.

1. Set the build number format like this :
   `$(date:yyyy.MM.dd)$(rev:.r)` to get the  INCREMENTAL number.
2. Define a `version` variable and set value with the suffix "`alpha`"
   using [logging command](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md) in PowerShell:

   ```
   $version = $env:BUILD_BUILDNUMBER +"-alpha"

   Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=version]$version"
   ```
3. Add a PowerShell task to run the script.
4. Use the `version` variable  to version your package in subsequent tasks.

You can reference below articles about the NuGet packages versioning:

- [Versioning NuGet packages in a continuous delivery world: part 1](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2016/05/03/versioning-nuget-packages-cd-1/)
- [Versioning NuGet packages in a continuous delivery world: part 2](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2016/05/18/versioning-nuget-packages-cd-2/)
- [Package versioning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/targets/nuget?view=vsts&tabs=web#package-versioning)

[image]